# Can we control traffic routing to instances on AWS ELB with code

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb

I have two instances under one Application Loadbalancer. Both instances are under the same target group with default routing.

> Can I control traffic routing to the instances at the application level?

I'd like to **deploy a new version of the code** to one instance and allow only a small amount of traffic to that instance for testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Route 53 can achieve this A/B Testing via weighted routing.

> Weighted routing lets you associate multiple resources with a single domain name (example.com) or subdomain name (acme.example.com) and choose how much traffic is routed to each resource. This can be useful for a variety of purposes, including load balancing and testing new versions of software.

RE: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/routing-policy.html#routing-policy-weighted

The architecture would comprise of two routes with different weights(https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/devops/introducing-application-load-balancer-unlocking-and-optimizing-architectures/):

[image]

The other optimized recommendation outlined in the article above is to use an application load balancer to rewrite the URLs instead of using DNS.

Comment: So I can point 95% traffic to one A record and 5% traffic to another server A record (server with new version A record) without ELB